# Math differences between GLSL and Metal

Tags: macos, glsl, metal

I play around with `GLSL` and got [this effect](http://glslsandbox.com/e#35086.0). And I tried to convert it to metal but I got some funky result for `y-axis` when it is smaller than 0:

[image]

There are these funny curvy crop off for most of the cubes above the horizon(<0). This is my `Metal` code:

```
static float mod(float x, float y)
{
    return x - y * floor(x/y);
}

static float vmax(float3 v) {
    return max(max(v.x, v.y), v.z);
}

float fBoxCheap(float3 p, float3 b) { //cheap box
    return vmax(abs(p) - b);
}

static float map( float3 p )
{   
    p.x = mod(p.x + 5,10)-5;
    p.y = mod(p.y + 5 ,10)-5;
    p.z = mod(p.z + 5 ,10)-5;

    float box = fBoxCheap(p-float3(0.0,3.0,0.0),float3(4.0,3.0,1.0));

    return box;
}
```

It is almost the same code in `GLSL`:

```
float vmax(vec3 v) {
    return max(max(v.x, v.y), v.z);
}

float box(vec3 p, vec3 b) { //cheap box
    return vmax(abs(p) - b);
}

float map( vec3 p )
{
    p.x=mod(p.x+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    p.y=mod(p.y+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    p.z=mod(p.z+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    return box( p, vec3(1.,1.,1.) );
}
```

How can I resolve this? 
I am fairly new to both `GLSL` and `Metal` but I find `Metal` is more tricky because of these math issue.

Comment: I notice the same effect in GLSL if using p-vec3(0.0,3.0,0.0). try with just p, without subtracting anything from it.

Comment: I tried. It become even funkier.

Comment: What's your definition of `mod`?

Comment: @warrenm I updated my code on `mod()`.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference here. You can create similar artifacts in the GL version by applying all of the same modifications you do in the Metal version. The problem is that offsetting the point after you fold space with `mod` violates the requirement that the SDF be Lipschitz continuous (i.e., the gradient must be <= 1 everywhere). If you want to translate the box, translate `p` before applying `mod`.

Comment: @warrenm You are right. I need to brush up more on SDF related math.

Comment: Cool. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a difference here. You can create similar artifacts in the GL version by applying all of the same modifications you do in the Metal version. The problem is that offsetting the point after you fold space with `mod` violates the requirement that the SDF be Lipschitz continuous (i.e., the gradient must be <= 1 everywhere). If you want to translate the box, translate p before applying `mod`.